# Module not found: Can't resolve './components' while import multiples function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import

How can i import multiples functional component from a single folder in react native ? 
for example Auth and Home component.
this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Auth from "./components/Auth"
import Home from "./components/Home"

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export default function App() {
  return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={Auth} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

this is what I tried:

```
import {Auth, Home} from "./components"
```

i get this error : **Module not found: Can't resolve './components'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this, you must create a new file like `components/index.js` then import components and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) them like this:

```
import Auth from "./Auth"
import Home from "./Home"

const components = {
   Home: Home,
   Auth: Auth
}
export components
```

for using the components in your main file (`app.js`) you can import components through following way:

```
import { Home, Auth } from './components'
```